# How to generalize an inherited method call and a composed method call

Tags: python, inheritance, composition

At work, I'm running into an issue where a piece of code takes in a class object, `obj`, where the object can be one of multiple classes. The code makes the following call:

```
obj.compute()
```

For one of the classes, `MyClass`, I made a refactorization from using inheritance to composition. Previously, that class would have inherited `compute()` from one of its parent classes, but now it's accessed using `obj.sub.compute()`, so this breaks the above call because the rest of the classes still have a `compute()` method.

I can think of a couple solutions to this problem:

1. In `MyClass`, after initialization the composition in its constructor, we can do:

```
self.compute = self.sub.compute
```

2. In the call sites for `obj.compute()`, we can do a type check. When `obj` is `MyClass`, we can call `obj.sub.compute()`

I don't know how appropriate these solutions are? Are there are alternatives?

Comment: Is using the name `compute` absolutely essential to your new method? I would avoid overriding inherited methods entirely if doing so makes it incompatible with what is expected of child classes.

Comment: It's a preference to use that name because they all essentially do similar things, but why does changing the name of the method help? Also, I don't think there's any overriding here. After the refactorization to use composition, `MyClass` no longer has a `compute` method and rather, it's accessed through it's composed object, `sub`

Comment: I misunderstood your original question. I thought you made a new compute method and moved the old method to `sub.compute`. If you didn't make a conflicting method, then it should be relatively easy to define `compute` on the new class that points to the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your refactored class should define `compute` to comply with the expected API.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.sub = ...

    def compute(self):
        return self.sub.compute()
```

Defining an *instance* attribute named `compute` is not the same as providing a method named `compute`, and it should not be the job of the caller to deal with a non-compliant object.

Comment: Ah got it makes sense. I think I oversimplified the OP a bit, but actually `MyClass` is inherited by `AnotherClass` and `AnotherClass`'s object is what's ultimately used to call `compute`. In this case, would it make more sense to define `compute` within `AnotherClass` or in `MyClass`? `MyClass` still makes the most sense to me

Comment: Hard to say without knowing why `MyClass` is a base class of `AnotherClass` in the first place.